# Web Worker Memory Leak?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, web-worker

I've been using [Chrome's Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline) view to attempt to track down some memory leaks in my page.  I've found one particular memory leak that results from instantiating web workers that I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of.

I've stripped down the page to just load the web worker and do nothing else.  Every time I refresh the page, the Document Count on Chrome's timeline view permanently increases by 1.  If I comment out the call to the Worker constructor, and begin refreshing the page, the document count increases and then decreases, effectively staying the same.  Manually terminating/closing the worker does not resolve the issue (although I can see the worker disappear when I look at the Sources tab of the developer tools).

Here is my trimmed down .htm file.  I am able to reproduce the issue with just this short chunk of html/javascript:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var worker_blob = new Blob(["var test = 1;"]);
var worker_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(worker_blob);
// Comment out the line below and the memory leak goes away
var worker = new Worker(worker_url);
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(worker_url);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: When your worker finishes its task it can [close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWorkerScope#close()) itself or your page may call `terminate`.

Comment: I've already tried both and neither one remedies the issue.  In addition, the worker should be terminated when I leave the page.

Comment: Is this by chance https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181680 ?

Comment: I can't say I fully understand the bug report, but it does appear to be related to the issue I'm encountering.  Hopefully this simple test case helps you reproduce/fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a memory leak in Chrome v25.  It appears to be fixed in Chrome v26, as the issue can no longer be reproduced.